# Spring AOP does not works in Tomcat and tcserver

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an aspect which works fine when I run it from a unit test or through a stand alone application. However when I run it as a part of web application and host it on Tomcat the Aspects are not applied.

My aspect looks like

```
public class MyAspect {

    @Around("within(com.service..*)")
    public Object doLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        //do something
        Object obj = pjp.proceed();
        //do something else
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see the same behavior in tcserver (Spring server which is on top of tomcat). Jboss also do not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve this. The reason was that the aspect were getting processed by web application context and not by global application context so I have to restructure couple of things. I have detailed the steps [here](http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/08/aop-in-spring-based-web-applications.html)

@seanizer Spring does support within. It's true that it is only applied to methods and in within it will apply to methods of all the package and sub package of com.service. For details check the reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

Comment: Yes, I admit, `within` is partially supported (when it applies to method executions). +1 to you

Comment: Unfortunately your link has disappeared from the web. The core of the linked content should have been included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I'll leave this in, because it's still partially valid, even if it didn't help in your case. I'll edit a few places though, edits are marked like <s>this</s> or *this*.

<s>If you're using Spring AOP, it can't work.</s> Spring AOP only *fully* supports the `execution` pointcut. The `within` pointcut *only works when it applies to method executions*, *for the full functionality of `within`* you will need AspectJ (Spring AOP only uses some AspectJ pointcuts, but not the AspectJ weaver). Either through static compilation (usually through [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) or [Ant](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks.html)) or through [Load-Time-Weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Also, your class is missing an `@Aspect` annotation.

Comment: within Pointcut does works with Spring. The above aspect works well when I run it through a stand alone application using Spring AOP only

Comment: *Spring AOP only supports method execution join points for Spring beans* Source: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts

Comment: You probably have AspectJ weaving turned on in your IDE, so you *think* you are using Spring AOP, whereas you're actually using AspectJ.

Comment: My IDE does not have AspectJ weaving turned on. Also I see the same problem when I directly deploy the war in the tomcat server and run the server from command line tool (so no ide involveed).

Comment: As I wrote: It's not supported by Spring AOP, and it can't be, since Spring AOP is based on JDK proxies per default, and they in turn are based on method interception. If you need more than that, use AspectJ (that's exactly what the Spring AOP docs suggest).

Answer (score 0):

How about move

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

to servlet-mvc.xml?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).